# Show bigger image on thumbnail's hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a list of images I have the urls for the squared thumbnail `http://example.com/img1_thumb.jpg`  and for the original size (any proportion) `http://example.com/img1.jpg`. I'm showing the thumbnails in a grid and I'd like to show the original one when the user puts the mouse over a image in the grid. Maybe using a floating element, the target is the user can see the image in more detail and view the parts of the cropped in the thumbnail.

How can I do it? I'm a beginner with HTML/css/Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can work without thumbnails..

**for thumbnail**

```
<img src="http://example.com/img1.jpg" class="compress"/>
```

on hover of the above show this one

```
$(".compress").hover(function(){
  $(".image").show();

});
```

**full image**

```
 <img src="http://example.com/img1.jpg" class="image"/>
```

**css**

```
 .compress{
  width:20%;
/*aspect ratio will be maintained*/

}

.image{
display:none;
position:absolute;


 }
```

its not complete,but i think it might help

Answer (score 11):

There are lots of jQuery plugins that do this. Since you are a beginner I would recommend starting there. [Here is an article](http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/) with some different options. [Here is an example of what you are looking for](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/).

Comment: great.  I was surprised how long it took to find something like this, with this simplicity.  I thought it'd be a common thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery:

```
$(function() {
      $('#thumbnails img').click(function() {
            $('#thumbnails').hide();
            var src = $(this).attr('src').replace('.png', 'Large.png');
            $('#largeImage').attr('src', src).show();
      });
      $('#largeImage').hide().click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $('#thumbnails').show();
      });
});

<div id="thumbnails">
<img src="thumbnail1.png">...
</div>
<img id="largeImage" src="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can create a `<div class="some_class"><img src="http://example.com/img1.jpg"></div>` set it's `display:none` and then bind an event to the `thumb div` like this :

```
$(".thumb_class").hover(function(){
   $(".some_class").show()
},
function(){
   $(".some_class").hide()
}
```

Of course you can personalize every `div` . The second `function` let you to `hide` the div when the mouse is out of the thumb. Hope i was as clear as possible.