# How to fix the code for hovering an image, then show a bigger version of that image with the same resolution?

Tags: html, css

I am currently writing a website and here is the outlook

[image: view_of_the_website].

Ideally, I want it to show me the same image, but with bigger size and same resolution. What I did is having 2 identical images, one big one small. Here is my code:

[image: HTML_code]

the "heading div" is the banner on top while the "content div" is the image as well as where I would like to have the hover effect. I played around and looked up many different ways to solve this online, but I still cannot figure out how to do so, can someone help me out please?

ADDED:
To be more direct on what I am trying to do, I made this Axure mock up: http://muzuf7.axshare.com . The idea here is having a smaller image on inside the tile and having a mouse-hover function. When hover to the smaller image, the bigger image shows up on top of the smaller image. It will be really clear if you interact with the Axure mock up that I did.

Comment: please add your code to the question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show bigger image on thumbnail's hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449437/show-bigger-image-on-thumbnails-hover)

Comment: I recommend you to try CSS background: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can do something like the following where you can increase the image's size on hover but contain it within a div using `overflow: hidden`. Obviously you can use transitions and whatnot to make this effect prettier than it is here:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="magic">
  <a id="hover"><img src="img.png" alt="Vienna Parliament" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#magic {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content img:hover {
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
}
```

Is that the type of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me out. I tried your code but it isn't working and I also think that I did not explain my problem well enough. I made this Axure mock up (http://muzuf7.axshare.com) and you can check it out. I do not want just enlarge the smaller image, because it loses resolution and that is why I have another larger image for this function.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution to this problem? If yes, I think something like the above will have to be your solution because you are not going to be able to hide element X by hovering element Y with only CSS. You could simply use the larger image in your HTML, sizing it down initially with CSS and then upping the size on hover. If not, can you not use the JS you have working in the mockup?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using Scale on Hover with Transition. Here I make small demo.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src=http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png " width="540 " height="548 ">
  
  <div class="item-overlay top "></div>
</div>
```

For more details & effects check [here](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/zoom.html)

Comment: Hi can you please help

Comment: Yes Sure. @pcpriyanka